# Prove that $\sup_n |T_n f(x)|<\infty,$ for a.a. $x$ for every $f \in L^1(R)$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Denote $K(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}\cdot(1+x^2)}$ and $K_n(x)=nK(xn), n\in\mathbb{N}$. For $f\in L^1(R),$ define $T_nf(x)=\int_R K_n(x-y)f(y)\, dy.$ Prove or disprove that for every $f\in L^1(R), \sup_n |T_nf(x)|<\infty$ for Lebesgue almost every $x$.

I tried doing this: $||T_nf(x)||_{L^1}\leq\int_R\int_R |K_n(x-y)f(y)|\, dy\, dx=||K_n||_{L^1}||f||_{L^1}=||K_1||_{L^1}||f||_{L^1}<\infty.$ So $|T_nf(x)|<\infty$ a.e for each n. Then I don't know how to prove $\sup_n |T_nf(x)|<\infty$ a.e.

Comment: You are asked to prove the $\sup_n |T_n f(x)|<\infty$ not $ \sup_n||T_nf(x)||_{L^1} $!.

Comment: it is to prove $|sup_n T_nf(x)|<\infty$

Comment: Can we prove that the mapping $sup_n T_n$ maps $L^1$ to $L^1$? If we can, then we are done.